# Upload a full directory to IPFS using ipfs (js-ipfs-http-client)

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I want to upload a directory to ipfs on my browser using (js-ipfs-http-client) module.
I found this old issue. https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/277 So I decided to use recursive way to add files and get only one hash for it.

```
ipfs.addFromFs('path', { recursive: true, ignore: ['subfolder/to/ignore/**'] }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) { throw err }
            console.log(result)
        })
```

But it gave me this error.

[image]

I need to upload a directory to ipfs using javascript but all resources I had found upload only one file.Or a lot of files with array of hashes. I need a way to upload all files of directory and get the with only one hash. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're trying to call functions from the `fs` module client-side rather than server-side.

Comment: I know but it's required to use solidity only on the backend. And js will used for fronted. I had already used cdn for fs module and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the issue you linked, it looks like the core module does not handle reading files from your system.

Instead, you must pass in a stream of files that IPFS can consume from.

Since you are doing this in the browser, it is a little more complicated to achieve.

Perhaps you might want to look into the [FileSystem Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), which offers the [showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker) functionality.

From there, you'll have to figure out how to pass these files into IPFS.

Unfortunately, this API [doesn't have great browser support](https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api) at the moment, although that is likely to improve with time. It is still experimental technology.